# cutting part of object

Tags: opengl, stencil

How to cut part of the object if it is inside a specific area? like showed on attached image.

[image]

PS

Looks like stencil should be used, but I am not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was achieved using stencil. 
case closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the area is a rectangle you can use a scissor rectangle. It sets that only part of the viewport gets drawn while everything outside of that is not drawn.

Comment: but I need other objects to be drawn outside of the rectangle, like on image. is that something scissor can do ?

Comment: @ChervonogradskyOleg you then only set the scissor on the objects that need it.

Comment: okay. thanks. do you know how to do such cut in local coordinates ?